# Getting rows one by one on refreshing by pulling down ,wanted whole array on viewdidload

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I reload the tableview by pulling down the refreshing controller , it gets me rows one by one  on each refreshing . I want all the data of rows in (view did load) and refreshing .
Table view is in view controller , I am getting one row in each refresh /reload, but want all rows on(view did load) and on refreshing .
 when I open the view I get one row and when I refresh the view I get one more row but wanted to have all rows in one time in (view did load) and refreshcontrol .
    there are three methods (view did load) / view will appear / refreshing control / I want the whole value of cartData on viewdidload.

---

```
 public struct FavouriteCart {
    var p_name : String!
    var p_price : String!
    var p_id : String!
    var qty: String!

 public init(p_name: String ,  p_price: String , p_id : String, qty: String) {
        self.p_name = p_name
        self.p_price = p_price
        self.p_id = p_id
        self.qty = qty
    }

}

 public struct favSection {
    var favitems: [FavouriteCart]

    public init(favitems: [FavouriteCart]  ) {
        self.favitems = favitems
    }
}


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.getFav()
       // self.reloadInputViews()

       // self.getFav()


        self.viewWillAppear(true)
          self.updateTableview()


        if btn2 != btn3 {
            lblPreorder.isHidden = true
            lblOrdermethod.isHidden = false
            print("BUTTONCLICKED")
             UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "button1")
        } else if btn2 == btn3 {
            lblPreorder.isHidden = false
            lblOrdermethod.isHidden = true
            print("BUTTON-NOT-CLICKED")
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "button1")
        }


//        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
//        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
//        self.getFav()
//        self.updateTableview()



        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        print("111111111 ->  \(cartid)")

        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        } else {
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

        }
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newCartViewController.refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
//

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      self.refreshData()
//        self.refreshData()
//        self.getFav()
      //  self.updateTableview()


    }


    @objc func refreshData() {

        self.getFav()
        self.getTotal1()
        self.updateTableview()

        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    }

    func updateTableview() {

      DispatchQueue.main.async{

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    // Mark: getting all cart items:-->
    func getFav(){
        let request = getApi.displaycartGetWithRequestBuilder(restId: "17", cartId:cartid!)
        Alamofire.request(request.URLString, method: .get , parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("123321/\(response)")
                let res = response
                print("101res/\(res)")

                let total =  self.cartData
                print("cartd1/\(total)")

    if let value = response.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let success = value["error"] as? Bool {
            if success == false {
                print("2222/\(response)")
            if let response = value["cartdata"]  as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let cart = response["simple"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                var itemsdata: [FavouriteCart] = []
                                for (_ , value) in cart.enumerated() {

                                    let obj = value as! [String:AnyObject]
                                    let p_name = obj["p_name"] as! String
                                    let p_price = obj["p_price"] as! String
                                    let p_id = obj["p_id"] as! String
                                    let qty = obj["qty"] as! String

                                    var prid = p_id as! String
                                    print("stirng ID - > /\(p_id)")
                                    let item = FavouriteCart(p_name: p_name, p_price: p_price, p_id: p_id, qty: qty)

                                    itemsdata.append(item)



                                // self.cartData.append(favitems)

                                   print("hiiooooooooooooooooooooooo/\(itemsdata)")

                                }
                self.cartData.append(favSection(favitems: itemsdata))
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert",message:value["error_msg"] as? String,preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK",style:UIAlertActionStyle.default , handler: nil)
                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    // Mark:--> Delete items from cart.
    // func delFav(p_id: String ,completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    func delFav(product_id: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
        //var product1 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "p_id")
        //print("this is my \(product1)")
    let request = getApi.deleteproductcartGetWithRequestBuilder(restId: "17", cartId: cartid!, productId: product_id , freeDish: "none", type: "simple")
        Alamofire.request(request.URLString, method: .delete , parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("del favvvvvvvvv\(response)")
                //print(response)
                if let value = response.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    if let success = value["error"] as? Bool {
                        if success == false {
                            let response = value["cartdata"] as? [String]
                            print("10001 - > /\(response)")

                            //self.tableView.reloadData()


                        } else
                        {
                            print("error message")
                        }
                    }

                }
                // completionHandler(true)
        }
    }


    func delterow(product_id: String) {
        self.delFav(product_id: product_id, completionHandler: {sucess in
            if sucess {
                print("DELETED_ITEM")
            }
        })
    }


}

extension newCartViewController: UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource{



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90;
    }

//    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
//       return cartData.count
//    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      // return sectionsData[section].items.count

      return cartData.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartTablecell", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCell

    let item: FavouriteCart = cartData[indexPath.section].favitems[indexPath.row]

     cell.btnsub1.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.btnadd1.tag = indexPath.row


        cell.lblItemName.text = item.p_name
        cell.productPrice.text = item.p_price
        cell.lblprice.text = item.p_price



        return cell


    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool{
        return true

    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if (editingStyle ==  .delete) {
        let item: FavouriteCart = cartData[indexPath.section].favitems[indexPath.row]
        self.delterow(product_id: item.p_id)

        self.tableView.reloadData()

       }

    }


}
```

Comment: uncomment self.getFav() from viewDidLoad

Comment: That's a serious amount of code (and empty lines and print lines and commented lines), could you clear it up by making it more compact and removing anything not relevant for your issue?

Comment: is their Any  solution to my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
used completion handler in the api call and reloaded the data in the  api call :-----


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       // self.getFav()
       //self.viewWillAppear(true)
      // refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewDidAppear(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newCartViewController.refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)


        if btn2 != btn3 {
            lblPreorder.isHidden = true
            lblOrdermethod.isHidden = false
            print("BUTTONCLICKED")
             UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "button1")
        } else if btn2 == btn3 {
            lblPreorder.isHidden = false
            lblOrdermethod.isHidden = true
            print("BUTTON-NOT-CLICKED")
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "button1")
        }


//        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
//        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
//        self.getFav()
//        self.updateTableview()



        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        print("111111111 ->  \(cartid)")

        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        } else {
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

        }



    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.updateTableview()

        self.getFav()

    }


       @objc func refreshData() {

        self.getFav()
        self.getTotal1()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
         }


    func updateTableview() {
      DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }



    func getFav() {
        getFav(completionHandler: { success in
            if success {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    //TOTAL API CALL:
    func getTotal1() {
        let request = getApi.getamountcartGetWithRequestBuilder(restId: "17", cartId: (cartid as? String)!)
        Alamofire.request(request.URLString, method: .get , parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("123321#######/\(response)")
                let res = response
                print("101res/\(res)")


        if let value = response.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let success = value["error"] as? Bool {
            if success == false {
            var  grandtotal = value["total"] as Any
                var gtotal = grandtotal

                print("^^^^^/\(gtotal)")
            print("@@@@/\(grandtotal)")

       UserDefaults.standard.set(10, forKey: "gtotal")


                        }
                    }
                }
          }
    }
//
    // Mark: getting all cart items:-->
    func getFav(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
        let request = getApi.displaycartGetWithRequestBuilder(restId: "17", cartId:cartid!)
        Alamofire.request(request.URLString, method: .get , parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("123321/\(response)")
                let res = response
                print("101res/\(res)")

                let total =  self.cartData
                print("cartd1/\(total)")

    if let value = response.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let success = value["error"] as? Bool {
            if success == false {
                print("2222/\(response)")
            if let response = value["cartdata"]  as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let cart = response["simple"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
//                let total = value["total"] as! [String: Any]
//                print("1231231231234/\(total)")
                                //let userdata: [Favourites] = []
               //
                var cartData: [FavouriteCart] = []
                                for (_ , value) in cart.enumerated() {

                                    let obj = value as! [String:AnyObject]
                                    let p_name = obj["p_name"] as! String
                                    let p_price = obj["p_price"] as! String
                                    let p_id = obj["p_id"] as! String
                                    let qty = obj["qty"] as! String
                                  //  UserDefaults.standard.set(qty, forKey: "qty")
                                    var prid = p_id as! String
                                    print("stirng ID - > /\(p_id)")
                                    let item = FavouriteCart(p_name: p_name, p_price: p_price, p_id: p_id, qty: qty)

                                    cartData.append(item)
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                        print("RELOADED-----ON-----API")
                                        self.cartData.append(favSection(favitems: cartData))
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    }
//                                   self.tableView.reloadData()

                                // self.cartData.append(favitems)


                                    //QTY::::::-------
//                                    let quant = QtyCart(qty: qty)
//                                    self.qtyData.append(quant)
//

                                   //print("hiiooooooooooooooooooooooo/\(itemsdata)")

                                }


                            }
                print("COMPLETION-------------HANDLER")
                completionHandler(true)
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert",message:value["error_msg"] as? String,preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK",style:UIAlertActionStyle.default , handler: nil)
                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```